# Get the magento cart quantity with ajax

Tags: cart, ajax

Im currently having a problem with ajax and magento. I'm trying to get the current amount of items in a cart, after the user has clicked on the "put in cart"-button of an product, without reloading the page.

So far I've tried it with a poorly written Ajax, which hasn't worked, because I'm an absolute beginner with Ajax.

The process should be following:
User clicks on "add to cart" -> script requests new cart quantity with ajax -> jquery adds the current amount into another DOM-Element (lets name it #cartqty)

My current non-ajax solution doesn't work, which looks like this:

```
$( '.product-add-btn' ).click(function() {
    $( '#cartqty' ).html('<?php echo $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getSummaryCount(); ?>');
});
```

The problem is NOT how to add a product with ajax to the cart. The problem is how to get the current amount of items in the cart with ajax after a product has been added to the cart, just for clarification.

My current code just gives back the first known cart item quantity, which is say 4. When I add something again, the quantity doesn't update, it just stays at 4, even if there are 5 products in the cart.

I really hope some can help a beginner.

Comment: you could create a controller action which returns the number of items in the cart and then call that action with ajax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  $( '#cartqty' ).html('<?php echo $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getSummaryCount(); ?>'); not ajax call .
```

1. Call `an ajax` on `button click` to new url.
2. Get data from  that New Url.so you need to `new Action on exit any controller` or `create new controller and get data` .

`<script>
$( '.product-add-btn' ).click(function() {
     new Ajax.Request(url, {
            method:'get',
             onLoading:function(){    },
            onSuccess: function(transport) {
              if (200 == transport.status){ 
                     var response = transport.responseText.evalJSON( );
                       $( '#cartqty' ).html(response.count );
                }else{
                    alert('Something went wrong...');
                }
              },
            onFailure: function() { alert('Something went wrong...'); }
            });
});
</script>`

Need to create a controller by create new module:

```
<?php
class Amit_Custommodule_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{
public function indexAction(){
    $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getSummaryCount();
    $result=array();
    $result['count']=this->helper('checkout/cart')->getSummaryCount();
    $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-type','application/json',true);
    $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
    }
}
```

### Full module:

- First of all create module control file Module name as 
  `Amit_Custommodule.xml at app/etc/modules/`.

**Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Amit_Custommodule>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
            <active>true</active>
        </Amit_Custommodule>
    </modules>
</config>
```

- Path Of `config.xml` is `app/code/community/Amit/Custommodule/etc`

**Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Amit_Custommodule>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Amit_Custommodule>
    </modules>

    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <custommodule>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Amit_Custommodule</module>
                    <frontName>custommodule</frontName>
                </args>
            </custommodule>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

- **IndexController.php** path is `app/code/community/Amit/Custommodule/controllers/`

Code:

```
<?php
class Amit_Custommodule_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{
public function indexAction(){

    $result=array();
    $result['count']=Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getSummaryCount();
    $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-type','application/json',true);
    $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
    }
}
```

**And script:**

```
<script>
$( '.product-add-btn' ).click(function() {
     new Ajax.Request('<?php echo $this->getUrl("custommodule/index/index")?>', {
            method:'get',
             onLoading:function(){    },
            onSuccess: function(transport) {
              if (200 == transport.status){ 
                     var response = transport.responseText.evalJSON( );
                       $( '#cartqty' ).html(response.count );
                }else{
                    alert('Something went wrong...');
                }
              },
            onFailure: function() { alert('Something went wrong...'); }
            });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Stupid question, where should I put the controller?

Comment: update check this....

Comment: I didn't chagned anything, do I need to replace url, method, params and so on with my own parameters? Right now, out of the bow, I get the following error in the console: ReferenceError: url is not defined

new Ajax.Request(url, {

Comment: update ..please check'

Comment: Worked like a charme! You're awesome! Thank you so much. :)

Comment: It seems that the script has some hiccups. It gives back 6 items when there are 7 items in the cart. Any idea why this is happening? Or 31 when there are 32 items. Any idea what causes this hiccup?

Comment: you need  to call ajax after addtocart done.. currently  you get cart quanity before complete  addtocart done

Comment: A little wait should fix it, right?